# Syntax highlighting in <pre> tags

Tags: python, html, css, syntax-highlighting, pre

Are there any libraries that will allow me to display code in `<pre>` tags and highlight the syntax according to the language? I'm imagining something like this:

```
<pre class="python">
class MyClass:
    """A simple example class"""
    i = 12345
    def f(self):
        return 'hello world'
</pre>
```

...where the CSS for `pre.python` would highlight the Python code appropriately.

Does something like this exist?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There's [SyntaxHighlighter](https://github.com/syntaxhighlighter/syntaxhighlighter):

```
<pre class="brush: python">
   # python code here
</pre>
```

There's also [highlight.js](https://highlightjs.org/) which has the option of automatically detecting the syntax and highlighting it appropriately; however, you would need to use both `<pre><code>` tags to wrap your code.

If you're looking for a server-side example, there's [GeSHi](http://qbnz.com/highlighter/) or [Pygments](https://pygments.org/) for Python.

Comment: You don't need to use <pre><code> with highlight.js, you can use any markup you want. <pre><code> is just a default (and an HTML5 recommendation, FWIW)

Comment: Jumping onto the last comment, you can do this with code like the following:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
  document.querySelectorAll('pre').forEach((el) => {
    hljs.highlightElement(el);
  });
});
```

See "custom usage" at https://highlightjs.org/usage/

Answer (score 6):

I prefer [**highlight.js**](https://highlightjs.org/). It supports [112 languages](https://highlightjs.org/static/demo/).

Preview your page with this code injection from the browser console:

```
// Highlight 22 popular code types. TODO: Inline for speed and security.
function loadjscssfile(filename, filetype){  // http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/loadjavascriptcss.shtml
    if(filetype=="js"){
        var fileref=document.createElement('script')
        fileref.setAttribute("type","text/javascript")
        fileref.setAttribute("src", filename)
    }
    else if(filetype=="css"){
        var fileref=document.createElement("link")
        fileref.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet")
        fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/css")
        fileref.setAttribute("href", filename)
    }
    if(typeof fileref!="undefined") document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref)
}
loadjscssfile("//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/8.4/styles/vs.min.css", "css")
loadjscssfile("//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/8.4/highlight.min.js", "js")
setTimeout("var a = document.querySelectorAll('.code'); for(var i=0; i < a.length; ++i) hljs.highlightBlock(a[i])", 600)
```

Comment: Tried the preview - Awesome! I couldn't find an option for dark-mode, but this [dracula.css](https://draculatheme.com/highlightjs) does the job quite nicely.

Answer (score 1):

**First Download or Using CDN**

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset("assets/css/prism.css")}}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset("assets/css/prism-unescaped-markup.min.css")}}">

<script src="{{asset("assets/js/prism.js")}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset("assets/js/prism-unescaped-markup.min.js")}}"></script>
```

**With HTML only**

```
<script type="text/plain" class="language-markup">
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Hello World!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>This text should be syntax highlighted.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
  </body>
</html>
</script>
```

**With Any**

```
<code class="language-css">
   p { color: red }
</code>
```

Comment: Unsure, but `{{` and `}}` is likely not meant to be in there, and the `<!DOCTYPE html>` doesn't seem to work inside the `<script>`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you're after, but when I want syntax-highlighted code blocks in a document, I write the document in [Pandoc-Markdown](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/README.html#pandocs-markdown), then use [Pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/) to process the doc into html.

You get the highlighted code block using pandoc-markdown syntax like this:

```
~~~{.python}
class MyClass:
    """A simple example class"""
    i = 12345
    def f(self):
        return 'hello world'
~~~
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can use [SyntaxHighlighter](https://github.com/syntaxhighlighter/syntaxhighlighter). It's easy to use, exactly the thing you need. Just add the `code` tag in your `pre` block.

It highlights about 23 languages including Python.